# Can JSON contained in a string property of another JSON be described via JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

If I have an object like this:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "details": "{\"age\": 30, \"email\": \"john@example.com\"}"
}
```

Is it possible to describe nested JSON in `"details"` with a schema inside of an outer schema?

I imagine something like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "details": {
      "type": "string",
      "contentMediaType": "application/json", 
      "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
           "age": {
             "type": "number"
           },
           "email": {
             "type": "string"
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are using the latest draft, 2020-12. See [section 8. A Vocabulary for the Contents of String-Encoded Data](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#section-8). You already have the `contentMediaType`; this draft adds `contentSchema`.

Note, however, that you will find *very* limited support in tooling for validating the decoded JSON against this schema. The spec states "[these keywords] do not function as validation assertions; a malformed string-encoded document MUST NOT cause the containing instance to be considered invalid." So, yes, you can *describe* the contents of the JSON string, but that description will not be validated unless your application takes further steps to perform that validation.

Comment: interesting, hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No</strike>, the `details` is only validated as a `string`. Any further validation of the `contentSchema` property is not validated other than being a `string` value and if any other constraints are placed upon the string instance, such as `minLength` or `maxLength`.

revising my comment to provide a valid code block based on JSON Schema 2020-12.

To Ethan's comment, at the time of writing, support for vocabularies is few and far between. You can find which implementations are supporting from [JSON Schema implementations - Validators](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators)

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "details": {
            "type": "string",
            "contentMediaType": "application/json",
            "contentSchema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "age": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```